# Micropython Esp8266 Sympy

Tags: python, sympy, esp8266, micropython

Can I use Sympy library in esp8266 micropython?

I tried to install it using ampy, but it returns an error

I want to solve linear equations:

For example:

```
from sympy import symbols, Eq, solve

y = symbols('x')
eq1 = Eq(x*2 -5x + 6)
sol = solve(eq1)
```

Error:

> Import sympy Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 1, in  File "/lib/sympy/**init**.py", line 15, in  ImportError: no module named 'future'

And when I`m trying to install future it returns an error raise:

> PyboardError('exception', ret, ret_err) ampy.pyboard.PyboardError: ('exception', b'', b'Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n File "", line 6, in \r\nOSError: [Errno 13] EACCES\r\n')

Comment: Show the error message.

Comment: import sympy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/lib/sympy/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
ImportError: no module named '__future__'
>>> 

And when I`m trying to install future it returns an error 

raise PyboardError('exception', ret, ret_err)
ampy.pyboard.PyboardError: ('exception', b'', b'Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File "<stdin>", line 6, in <module>\r\nOSError: [Errno 13] EACCES\r\n')

Comment: Did adding micropython-future help? Did you succeed in running SymPy under micropython?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are trying to use a library in MicroPython (or Python) and you get an import error it means a library needed by that library is missing or unavailable.

It may be missing because a dependency was not installed or it may be missing due to differences in Python version (2.x vs 3.x or CPython vs. MicroPython)

In this case, `future` is not a module available in the MicroPython standard library. There is a "future" module library. You can see here: https://libraries.io/pypi/micropython-future and https://github.com/micropython/micropython-lib. Try adding this to your ./lib and see if sympy works.